# Constrain input parameter to supertype of some generic type, and making result type that same type

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm trying to make a type safe GraphQL data fetching method. I use the types generated on the server and want to select a subset of properties defined on these types to be the result type.

The generated code from the server looks like

```
export interface Dream {
    id: number;
    title?: string;
}

export interface IQuery {
    dream(id: number): Dream | Promise<Dream>;
}
```

The function to retrieve the data:

```
function doQuery<
    QName extends keyof IQuery,
    QParams extends Parameters<IQuery[QName]>,
    R extends Partial<ReturnType<IQuery[QName]>>
>(queryName: QName, params: QParams, resultSelector: R): R {
    return {} as R; // stub
}
```

And a utility class that makes it possible to use "types" at runtime

```
class types {
    static number: number;
    static string: string;
    static boolean: boolean;
}
```

When calling the function with for example

```
const result = doQuery("dream", [2], {
    title: types.string
});
```

The result type is correctly inferred as

```
const result: {
    title: string;
}
```

Also when I call

```
const result = doQuery("dream", [2], {
    nonExisting: types.string,
});
```

the compiler throws `Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'nonExisting' does not exist in type 'RecursivePartial<Dream>`, which is what I want.

However, when calling the function with

```
const result = doQuery("dream", [2], {
    id: types.number,
    nonExisting: types.string,
});
```

The compiler says it is OK, which I do not want it to be. I would like the compiler to throw in the same way as before.

The resulting type should always be of the same type as the resultSelector type.

In the code I have experimented with so far, the possibility of the result of the query being `Dream | Promise<Dream>` is not handled yet. This should be possible with conditional types I believe.

Also the Partial part is the best I could come up with, but it should actually be so that `ReturnType<IQuery[QName]> extends R` instead of the other way around, which I do not know how to express this in Typescript.

Is it possible to implement the constraints I am looking for in the current state of the art of Typescript? If so, how? If not, why not?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work with

```
type Awaited<T> = T extends { then(onfulfilled: (value: infer U) => any): any }
    ? U
    : T extends { then(...args: any[]): any }
    ? never
    : T;
```

and

```
type Subset<S, F> = { [key in keyof S]: key extends keyof F ? F[key] : never };
```

and

```
function doQuery<
    QName extends keyof IQuery,
    QParams extends Parameters<IQuery[QName]>,
    R extends Subset<R, Awaited<ReturnType<IQuery[QName]>>>
>(queryName: QName, params: QParams, resultSelector: R): R {
    return {} as R;
}
```